# How in excel4node apply style or type or else to an entire row/column without be forced to loop through all the cells

Tags: javascript, excel4node

I'm trying to use the NPM package `excel4node` link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node)

I don't have any snippets yet to share as I'm primarily concerned if anyone knows, how to apply a style, type, or else to an entire row/column of an Excel sheet.

The documentation is not very clear and I cannot understand how I can avoid always having to loop through all the cells to apply specific things as a style for example.

For example, I would like one specific column every cell in that will have wrap text true. How can that be done?

Difficult to find any example online or clear documentation.